# Online backup of Ubuntu 18.04 VM on Hyper-V 2019

Tags: backup, ubuntu-18.04, windows-server-backup, windows-server-2019

I have created a Generation 2 VM running Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.

I would like to do an online backup of this VM to another disk in the server (and eventually to a NAS).

After adding the Windows Server Backup feature, I ran the Backup Schedule action and went to add the VM to the scheduled backup.

Unfortunately, the wizard shows `(Offline)` next to the Ubuntu Server VM instead of `(Online)` like it shows for all the other VMs (CentOS and various Windows Servers).

Is there any way to do an online backup of this Ubuntu Server 18.04 guest? I have made sure the `Backup (volume shadow copy)` is enabled under `Integration Services` for the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Linux Integration Services kernel modules, [available from Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v), you can take online file system consistent snapshots. It does not use VSS, I am unsure as to whether that integration checkbox should be on or off for Linux.

Follow LIS install instructions from Microsoft, notably `apt-get install linux-azure`  and reboot into this kernel.

To get application consistent snapshots, like suspending database writes, you will need hook scripts. [Azure Backup has application backup hooks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-linux-app-consistent), for example. Edit your question if you need this, it requires integration specific to the application you are backing up.

Comment: `apt-get install linux-azure` seemed to do the trick. Online backups are now available. Good point about the application consistent backup hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Online backups are only applicable to VSS capable guests, meaning the guest needs to have VSS... which I'm pretty certain is exclusive to to the Windows operating system.

Comment: CentOS is a Linux distribution and I can do an online backup of it?